# Checking the increment in values in a dict and saving it to json

Tags: python, json, loops, dictionary, counter

We have a dict with three different values : `{value1: 1, value2 :0, value3: 2}` saved in a json file Each time we run a code those values increase by one, for example, it becomes : `{value1: 2, value2 :1, value3: 3}`.

I am trying to add a rolling counter check to my code where it checks if the values have incremented by 1 or not. Once it is checked, another dict is created with the new values (we end up having two dict). If we run the code again after increasing the values in the first dict manually by 1 for example, it checks again if those values have incremented by one comparing to the previous run and overwrite the new dict with the new values.

In other words, this is what I tried

```
#generally this step is saving three different values in X.json from another file. 
#The values in that file is increased in each iteration and 
#hence this part of code where am checking if the increase by one is happening

X_dict = dict ()
with open('X.json', 'w') as f4:
    f4.write(json.dumps(X_dict))    

#check if file exist

if os.path.exists("X.json"):

    #read the file

    with open('X.json', 'r') as old:

        #create a new dictionary

        NEW = dict ()

        #saving the data in the initial X in old to use a comparison

        OLD = json.load(old)
        for  key,value in NEW.items():

            #I would say that am trying to comapre old and new values
            #new values are obtained after running code second time and having 
            #values in X changed while old dict have the older values

            if new_value = old_value + 1:
                NEW[key] = X[key]
            
            else:
                NEW[key] = OLD[key]

#if file does not exist to start with

else:
    with open('X.json', 'w') as f5:
        f5.write(json.dumps(X_dict))
```

Values in the `NEW` dict should be added/updated however I am not getting anything and the dict remains empty.

Comment: You're always replacing the file with an empty dict at the beginning of the script.

Comment: Where is declared X?

Comment: `if NEW == OLD + 1:` How do you expect that to work? `NEW` and `OLD` are dictionaries, not numbers. I think you mean `if value = OLD[key] + 1:`

Comment: `for  key,value in NEW.items():` That won't do anything, since you just created `NEW` as an empty dictionary.

Comment: Is `X[key]` supposed to be `X_dict[key]`?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you're really trying to do. Every time you run the script, variables start empty. What are you comparing with the file to see if you've already incremented? Is this a function that could be called multiple times in the same script run?

Comment: I am trying to do the following, I have a file with three diff values that I can change manually. Before I change those values, they are saved in another file, when I change those values in the original files, before they are saved in the new file they need to be checked if there was an increment of values, if there is, the new file is overwritten with the new values.